# How can I create an upload page for (and only visible to) specific users?

Tags: user-access, uploads

I'm working on a WordPress site we have for some software my lab is developing. What I'd like to do is add a page that would allow collaborating groups to upload their data to us for testing, but that would be hidden from anyone else visiting the site (i.e. the collaborators would have to be logged in to see the page). Ideally they wouldn't see the dashboard when logged in, but that's not too much of an issue at the moment. Are there any plugins that would make this easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin [Omni Secure Files](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/omni-secure-files/) has quite a nice upload interface and different wordpress user roles can be given permission to either upload or just view the uploaded files

**Update from comment**

Here's the code I put into a page template to get the basics of OSF working in the front of the site:

```
if (!empty($omni_secure_files)) {
    wp_register_style('omni-secure-files',$omni_secure_files->plugin_url.'css/style.css',array(),false,'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('omni-secure-files');                          
    $omni_secure_files->menu_root();
}
```

The `wp_register_style / wp_enqueue_style` is necessary if you want to style it nicely. You mostly need to copy the required admin styles into the page template. At some point I might get round to releasing it as an extension to the plugin. I think the folks that wrote the plugin will probably get round to it at some point. It did take a lot of work though, so its no easy fix.

Comment: This looks great, especially the fact that it can handle large file sizes. Is there anything like this for the front end, or a front end component that ties into it? It'd be nice if the collaborating groups didn't have to deal with the back end of the site at all.

Comment: In the work I did for a client I did get it working in a page template - I've added the base code I used into my answer

Answer (score 0):

try [Page Restrict](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pagerestrict/) Plugins then create a page for uploading